# Modifying HTML <script> auto complete on Sublime Text 2

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 2 when inserting an html script tag using auto complete the cursor jumps to the end of the tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>*CURSOR HERE*
```

How can i modify the auto completion in Sublime so when I tab-complete an html script tag a src-attribute is added to the tag and the cursor jumps to the quotes of the src-attribute?

I found the following line in the Sublime HTML.sublime-completions file:

```
{ "trigger": "script", "contents": "<script type=\"${1:text/javascript}\">$0</script>" }
```

I tried modifying it to the following:

```
{ "trigger": "script", "contents": "<script type=\"${1:text/javascript}\" src=\"$1\">$0</script>" }
```

For this I referenced the html link tag in the file:

```
{ "trigger": "link", "contents": "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"$1\">" }
```

I tried installing another package called HTMLAttributes, but this didn't add the functionality i want.

I also tried modifying the script tag, i removed the type, but Sublime can still auto complete it. Am I modifying it wrong? Or in the wrong file?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to add the following code in html_completions.py located in the packages folder.

```
("script\tTag", "script type=\"${2:text/javascript}\" src=\"$1\">$0</script>" ),
```

More information: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html

Comment: I don't find this file in ST3, and the above-linked page is 404. Any further help?

Comment: P.S  don't use <Tab> which triggers Emmet. Use <Enter> instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a technique I found for accomplishing this in Sublime Text 3, using ST's snippets tool.**

1) Click `Menubar / Tools / New Snippet…`.

2) After the `<content><![CDATA[` and before the `]]></content>` text, replace the `Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.` text with `script src="$1"></script>` (customize this as you wish; **the `$1` indicates cursor placement after autocomplete**).

3) Uncomment the tab-trigger line, and change the `hello` text to `script`.

4) Uncomment the scope line, and change the `source.python` text to `text.html`.

5) Save the file to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User` and name it something like `html-script.sublime-snippet` (**it must end in `.sublime-snippet`**).

The complete file should look something like:

```
<!-- ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User -->
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[script src="$1"></script>]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>script</tabTrigger>
  <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

If written as above, when you begin to type `<script` (even just `<s`), you can then press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd> to autocomplete, and Sublime will populate `<script src=""></script>` and leave your cursor placed between the two double-quotation marks.

Documentation:

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Comment: That is very nice. But would it be possible to be able to autocomplete the src attribute as well, navigating on the filesystem and getting suggestions? Brackets does it in a very nice way, but it's too slow to be usable in (slightly-)larger projects, unfortunately.

Comment: @Nighto: I think you would need either to hard-code the `src` attr, or drop a cursor marker there and type. Unless there's some plugin to enable file browsing (I don't know of one).

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget if you have [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) installed you can use its' abbreviations too.

For example typing:

```
script:src<TAB>
```

Will resolve to:

```
<script src="|"></script>
```

And for CSS links:

```
link<TAB>
link[/path/to/my.css]<TAB>
```

Resolves to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="|">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my.css">|
```

(pipes indicated cursor positions)